# How to write a program to upgrade USB device firmware in windows

Tags: windows, usb

I have a USB device that uses the inbox class driver.
How can I write a program to update its FW?
Can I avoid writing a driver by using the WinUSB library?
It doesn't make sense to me that I am using the inbox driver and I will need to write a driver only for the common operation of FW upgrade.

Thanks,
Shai

Answer (score 0):

> I have a USB device that uses the inbox class driver.

This class uses HID as base. You could use HID to update the Firmnware too, eliminating the need to provide custom drivers. WinUSB needs at least an inf file.